# How to open a list type data in a file and print it

Tags: python

I have some data stored in the below format in text file textname.txt.
I want to open my data and store it in a list

Data in my file:

```
 ['item1.1,item1.2', 'item2', 'item3']
```

My approach:

```
with open('Location.txt','r') as g:
list2 = []
list2 = g.read()
print(list[0])
print(list[1])
print(list[2])
```

Output that is coming:

```
[
'
i
```

Desired Output:

```
item1.1,item1.2
item2
item3
```

Comment: This almost certainly an XY problem, you should not have written the list to a text file in the first place. Instead store the data using `pickle` or similar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing the file contents contains valid Python you can do:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("Location.txt") as f:
    data = literal_eval(f.read())
    print(data)
```

Though I'd advise against this in favour of storing the data in a more common storage format, like csv or JSON

Answer (score 1):

use `ast.literal_eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('test.txt') as g:
     l = ast.literal_eval(g.read())
     print '\n'.join(l)  # formatting to your output.



item1.1,item1.2
item2
item3
```